# Error occurred while issuing the access token Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are working on Azure SSO with SAML, after SAML response we've configured our inbound authentication as OAuth. After receiving SAML response on fetching the OAuth token we are getting below error,

Error occurred while issuing the access token for Client ID :, User ID null, Scope : [] and Grant Type : authorization_code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

```
 ERROR -  SAML Assertion Audience Restriction validation failed {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: SAML Assertion Audience Restriction validation failed
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.SAMLSSOAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(SAMLSSOAuthenticator.java:202)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:66)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:432)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:206)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:171)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:135)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.exception.SAMLSSOException: SAML Assertion Audience Restriction validation failed
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager.validateAudienceRestriction(DefaultSAML2SSOManager.java:826)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(DefaultSAML2SSOManager.java:471)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager.processResponse(DefaultSAML2SSOManager.java:312)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.SAMLSSOAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(SAMLSSOAuthenticator.java:157)
```

WSO2 IS Version: WSO2 5.1.0

Comment: You would have to provide more details, configuration, logs,...

Comment: @gusto2 updated with error log detail

Comment: see the exception `SAML Assertion Audience Restriction validation failed` , check what's really in the SAML token (EntityId, SP, ..) and it needs to match with the conf in the WSO2IS